# Google App Engine and upload multiple PHP files

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have a PHP project with about 30 files and 4 folders.
Is there a way to upload it to App Engine. I mean when I'm configuring YAML it uploads only index.php and nothing else.

Should I somehow upload files to GS and use YAML to point to those files?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is "Yes" you have to point your App to the GS where you're storing all the files.

Here is an example YAML file, that points to subdirectory that contains PHP files.

```html
runtime: php
# api_version: 1
env: flex
runtime_config:
  document_root: .
env_variables:
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET: "URL.appspot.com/public_html"
  MYSQL_USER: "NAME"
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: "USER"
  MYSQL_DSN: "mysql:dbname=DBNAME;unix_socket=/cloudsql/LOCATION"
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: "LOCATION"
```

Answer (score 0):

Static content can be served from Google Cloud Storage (GCS) or directly from GAE application environments. PHP files should be uploaded with your application rather than to GCS.

The GAE Flexible [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/serving-static-files) includes a discussion of each approach as well as a guide on getting started with serving static content from **GCS**.

In the **Standard environment** you have to [define handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref#app_yaml_Static_directory_handlers) that will serve your static content and map them to the directories in your project directory structure that hold the files. For example:

```
handlers:
# All URLs beginning with /stylesheets are treated as paths to
# static files in the stylesheets/ directory.
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets
```

All PHP files in your application directory will be uploaded unless included in your .gcloudignore file. By default the `vendor/` folder [is included there](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/specifying-dependencies) and thereby ignored, but that's because it's assumed that Composer will install necessary packages after deployment.

In the **Flexible environment**, anything under the document_root (specified in your [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/reference/app-yaml#the_runtime_config_section)) can be served by your application. PHP files in your application directory will be uploaded to the application environment unless specified under the `skip_files` element of your app.yaml.